# How to install packages from Docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, package-managers

Hi there I am new to Docker. I have an **docker-compose.yml** which looks like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  lmm-website:
    image: lmm/lamp:php${PHP_VERSION:-71}
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME:-lmm-website}
    environment:
      HOME: /home/user
    command: supervisord -n
    volumes:
      - ..:/builds/lmm/website
      - db_website:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 8765:80
      - 12121:443
      - 3309:3306
    networks:
      - ntw

volumes:
  db_website:

networks:
  ntw:
```

I want to install the Yarn package manager from within the docker-compose file:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
```

I could not figure out how to declare this, I have tried

```
command: supervisord -n && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
```

which fails silently. How do I declare this correctly? Or is docker-compose.yml the wrong place for this?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Why not use **Dockerfile** which is specifically designed for this task?

Change your "image" property to "build" property to link a Dockerfile.

Your docker-compose.yml would look like this:

```
services:
  lmm-website:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME:-lmm-website}
    environment:
      HOME: /home/user
    command: supervisord -n
      volumes:
        - ..:/builds/lmm/website
        - db_website:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 8765:80
      - 12121:443
      - 3309:3306
    networks:
      - ntw

volumes:
  db_website:

networks:
```

Then create a text file named Dockerfile in the same path as docker-compose.yml with the following content:

```
FROM lmm/lamp:php${PHP_VERSION:-71}

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y bash
```

You can add as much SO commands as you want using Dockerfile's RUN (cp, mv, ls, bash...), apart from other Dockerfile capabilities like ADD, COPY, etc.

**+info:**

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

**+live-example:**

I made a github project called **hello-docker-react**. As it's name says is a docker-react box, and can serve you as an example as I am installing yarn plus other tools using the procedure I explained above.

In addition to that, I also start yarn using an entrypoint bash script linked to docker-compose.yml file using docker-compose entrypoint property.

https://github.com/lopezator/hello-docker-react

Answer (score 4):

You can only do it with a `Dockerfile`, because the `command` operator in `docker-compose.yml` only keeps the container alive during the time the command is executed, and then it stops.

Comment: My containers continue running long after they've executed whatever I've specified in the "command" section.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
command: supervisord -n && apt-get update && apt-get install yarn
```

Because sudo doesn't work in docker.

Comment: Correct. But I tried and it seems like this is failing, too.

Answer (score -2):

My first time trying to help out:

would like you to give it a try (I found it on the internet)

```
FROM lmm/lamp:php${PHP_VERSION:-71}
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y bash
```

Comment: That won't do the trick. You posted content for a `Dockerfile` not for a `docker-compose.yml`