# Dockerized Gitea: Execute script outside of container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitea

I run gitea as Docker image with docker-compose. I have activated git hooks.

For one of my repositories, I want to run a post-receive git hook script. The repository is a (small) website and after every commit I want to checkout the repo, run a `make` command and a python script and upload the built files with `curl`.

**I want to execute the script outside the container with the `git` user of the outer system**. *Alternatively* it would be equally good to have git, make and python (with one or two additional modules) available inside the gitea docker system, so the whole deployment takes place from inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

My conclusion so far: If you want to trigger a deployment script, you should use Gitea's [webhooks](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/webhooks/). On the host system (or any other system), start up a server that consumes the webhook JSON and does whatever it should. In my case, this approach seems like a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Another option is to create a Dockerfile on the base of Gitea and add the necessary programs to run a server-side git hook inside the container. To do that, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47907859/2422617).

The original approach from my question, starting a script outside of the container with an outside user with access to outside programs, seems either outright impossible or at least not the "Docker way".